# phonegap file transfer is not uploading images to the server

Tags: cordova

I use phonegap file transfer API to transfer the files. All the text files are uploading fine. But images are not uploading . First it tells `'uploaded 115456 of 1177052 bytes'` But then it fails. It is giving timeout error saying error code 3 and http status null

```
var win = function() {
}
var fail = function() {
}
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.headers = {Connection : "close"}
  options.fileKey = "uploadFile";

    options.fileName = oneEntry.baseName;

  var mimeType;
  if (oneEntry.gips.i) {
    mimeType = "image/jpg";
  } else {
    mimeType = "text/plain";
  }
  options.mimeType = mimeType;
  options.chunkedMode = false;
  var params = new Object();
  params.action = "uploadFile";

  options.params = params;
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(oneEntry.fE.fullPath, "http://myserverpath", win, fail, options,true);
```

EDIT : As some links this file upload is a issue in higher version of cordova.But it works in lower version like cordova 1.9.0 . Is that true?? If so i must go back and change my cordova to 1.9.0 version from 2.5.0 version